# Enabling bulk admin privilege in amazon rds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wanted to setup an RDS instance store data for reporting. I have scrips that run different rest calls against certain sites that require bulk admin privilege on the back end because they dump their rest call data into a csv and then do a bulk csv insert into Sql Server SE. In my local environment setting up a user for my scripts to use with bulk admin privileges was easy. However, I couldn't seem to figure out how to do it in RDS. I opened a ticket with Amazon and they suggested writing a policy for it. So I figured I would ask here if this is possible and possible alternatives? If bulk/system admin privileges are out of the question in RDS I guess I will just have to use an AWS EC2 instance with Sql Server set up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk insert is not possible with RDS. The `data_file` parameter of the  `BULK INSERT` command must refer to a file accessible by the machine running SQL Server.

Also, RDS does not support the `bulkadmin` server role.

[Supported SQL Server Roles and Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.UnsupportedRoles)

[Importing and Exporting SQL Server Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)